# API observers, notify subscribers via REST API

Tags: rest, api, observer-pattern

I'm planning to build a web application where users can update some data.
Other developers should be able to subscribe to my application via an API and have to be notified if data has changed. With this notification there has to be the changed data sent to the subscriber. The subscribers app then automatically processes the received data.

`User changes data` -> `My webapps' datastore is being updated` -> `Notify all subscribers via REST or something like that over the internet` -> `Subscribers process changed data`

I'm currently in the planning phase and my problem is which technology to use, to build this notification system.

I don't know the code of the subscribing applications, so the interface between my application and the subscribing application must be something like a REST API.

I thought about using `Apache Kafka` or `RabbitMQ` to send those messages, but don't know if it's the right way to implement such functionality. I never did this kind of `Observer`-pattern between APIs myself.

Do you have any suggestion on this topic?

EDIT: `Apache Kafka` and `RabbitMQ` were only samples. I'm asking for your suggestions which technology fits best for this situation. It can be a solution without these types of messaging services at all.

Comment: As REST is based on a request-response interaction model, which is probably not sufficient for your subscriber service unless the clients are polling for notifications actively. Anything other might work but is not REST!

Comment: Or is it best practice to define an endpoint where the subscribing application can poll updates from and it is on the subscribing application to do this once per minute?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/) is based on push and pull based mechanism.Producer push data on a topic and consumer pulls data from that topic.We can defined the poll interval for consumer.

It is not based on observer design pattern. However rest services are available for data ingestion and data consumption which is know as [kafka rest proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/quickstart.html).

Like when user data changes , we write those changes on a topic like UserTopic using Producer Rest Service[Kafka Rest Proxy].We have already registered five consumers on topic UserTopic, they will consume the data using Consumer Rest Service[Kafka Rest Proxy].

Comment: However is it on the consumer to poll for new data changes in an defined interval or is it on my side to notify the consumer to poll the updated data?

Comment: It is the responsibility of the consumer to read the updated data and commit the offset.you can read about it from https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#theconsumer